# How can i get the table column name without the qualifier while executing the mdx query

Tags: ssas, mdx

When executing the below MDX query,

```
Select [Measures].[Internet Average Sales Amount] ON Columns, [Product].[Category].members ON Rows FROM [Adventure Works]"
```

I got one column name as `[Product].[Category].[Category].[MEMBER_CAPTION]` but I need `[Product].[Category].[Category]` alone as a column name.

Answer (score 0):

You are not completely flexible in SSAS with regard to result column names. The easiest approach is some column name change on the result consumer side. As you tagged your question "C#", I assume you are running the query from C# code. Just add a few lines of logic there before presenting the result to the user.